# Gradle builds really slow when adding new suites

Tags: gradle, testng

I"m using **Gradle** with **TestNG** to automate some tests on the web.
Im using the next structure on my gradle build file, whice runs TestNG XML suites:

```
test {

   useTestNG() {

    options{

    projectDir = rootDir

        suites('src/test/resources/CreateAgendaSuiteCase.xml', 
          'src/test/resources/CreateBasicEventSuiteCase.xml'
        , 'src/test/resources/CreateEventWithErrorsSuiteCase.xml', 
          'src/test/resources/SignInWithLiSuiteCase.xml'
        , 'src/test/resources/SignInWithUPSuiteCase.xml',
          'src/test/resources/AddPartnersSuiteCase.xml'
        , 'src/test/resources/AddPollsSuiteCase.xml',
          'src/test/resources/CreateNewUserLiSuiteCase.xml'
        , 'src/test/resources/CreateNewUserUPSuiteCase.xml', 
           'src/test/resources/UpgradePackageSuiteCase.xml')

 //,'src/test/resources/WebAttendee_SuiteCases/WebCreateNewUserEPSuiteCase.xml', 

  'src/test/resources/WebAttendee_SuiteCases/WebCreateNewUserLiSuiteCase.xml'
```

Every time I used **Gradle** it was just fine and made the build quite fast (~10 seconds), but when I added some new suites (those with the 'comments'), the build process takes forever (~5 minutes). Unfortunately. Gradle doesn't supply any hint or explanation (event with DEBBUG mode) for this situation.

Is anyone have encountered this problem? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps this suite simply takes a long time to run. You can also try to configure the `test` task with higher memory limits (see [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) for details), higher JVM fork rate (e.g. `forkEvery = 100`), or run tests in parallel (e.g. `maxParallelForks = 4`).

Comment: Thanks for the advises. I tried to add extra memory, but with no luck so far..
The weird thing is, that when I run the 'Problematic' suites alone (without the rest on the top), it runs just fine. The combination of all suites together somehow takes really long time.

Comment: Try to increase permgen memory limit via `test.jvmArgs` and/or set `forkEvery = 100`.